# How do I enable code highlighting in Visual Studio's Performance Analyzer window?

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2013

After I run a desktop C# project using Visual Studio 2013's "Instrumented" profiling, none of the code is highlighted in the Performance Analyzer's Function Code View window as shown in the screenshot below.

What can I try to make Visual Studio show the performance of each line of code a la http://stuartjames.info/Journal/visual-studio-12-performance-analysis.aspx?

[image: Visual Studio 2013 screenshot showing no code highlighting]

Comment: This has been bugging me for a while now... did you every find a fix?

Comment: No, I have not.

Comment: Problem still exists for me in MSVS 2017.